# How to remove anything but speech from 8 hours long file in audacity?

Tags: audacity, speech, human

**File**: 8 hours long.

**Task**: Let's say I recorded my training shift at work. I want to remove anything but human speech from 8-hour long file, in order to create checklists/flow diagrams based on what was said in my training.

**Output**: I'd like the output to be a shorter audio file, which contains only speech (some/normal level of background noise is not a problem).

**Question**: What's the most efficient/fastest way to do that?

Potentially (not a necessity) it would be useful if I could plug the output into speech-to-text software if that's supported by audacity.

Comment: Show us you at least did some research into this & where you failed to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protools has a "Split Silence" function which can be used to seperate out all elements where the audio level does not reach a particular threshold. Assuming that most of the audio is actually speech, then this is where I would start. Once you have all the speech segments, you can then 'shuffle' them down to a single region which you can then export.

Yes, there will be some manual work, but there isn't a plugin or app that will do this automatically that I am aware of.